How to use FastAPI-Cache2 package in the application
I want to implement Redis caching using FastAPI-Cache2 and I have implemented the caching based on the documentation:
async def init_cache():
    try:
        redis = aioredis.from_url(  # type: ignore
            appConfig.REDIS_ENDPOINT,
            encoding='utf-8',
            decode_responses=False,
        )
        FastAPICache.init(RedisBackend(redis), prefix='igw-cache')
        logging.info('Cache initialized successfully.')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error initializing cache: {e}')
        
  @asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(_app: FastAPI) -> AsyncIterator[None]:
    await init_cache()
    yield
        

and finally:
        app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan, docs_url=docs_url)
        
        @router.get("/test-cache")
@cache(expire=60)
async def index(request: Request, response: Response):
    logging.info('The endpoint executed...')
    return dict(hello="world")

whenever I call the endpoint, I see a unique key and value in the Redis but the The endpoint executed... log is also printed. How can I ensure it works as I expected to not see the logs for 60 seconds?

Well, I Implemented it the same, but I didn't encounter your problem my configs was:
Installation: pip install fastapi-cache2
initialization:
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # connect redis
    redis = Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
    app.state.redis = redis
    FastAPICache.init(RedisBackend(redis), prefix="fastapi-cache")
    yield
    app.state.redis.close()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

my router was:
@app.get('/test-cache')
@cache(expire=60)
async def test_cache():
    print('the router has executed')
    time.sleep(2)
    return dict(hello="world")

